# SQLite - looking for hello world-type html page app

Tags: sqlite, singlepage

I have done some googling but maybe I am not using the right terms ("sqlite reference web app"). I would like a example app which has a html page and writes submitted data to a sqlite database.

I know there are lots of examples out there, but they seem to require a lot of superstructure.

I am hoping - and maybe looking for something that does not exist - that there is a way to submit data to a SQLite database in a single web application folder structure.

Example:

/pub/docs/helloworld <-- in file structure, not deployed on web server

1. index.html - basic form with data section and form/submit button
2. foo.js - reads/writes data to hello.db
3. hello.db - sqlite database

Use case:

1. On load in a browser, index.html uses foo.js pulls a set of data from a view in hello.db and displays to the user.
2. User enters data and clicks submit.
3. index.html + foo.js update/create data in hello.db.

Do I need to install a full-blown app server for this, or can I do it with foo.js (+ a JS lib if required) only?

No, this is not a homework assignment, just trying to get a workbench for a project which I'd like to deploy on a shared internal filesystem instead of an application server.

I do know about TiddlyWiki and if it were a little more interactive querying-type structure where a user could search for a set of tags I might be able to use it, but I'm also interested in learning more about SQLite.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the context of a web browser, you will be limited by the possibilities of that browser.  You cannot access an SQLite database in an arbitrary file from browser-based Javascript.

The new HTML 5 standard does have a localStorage mechanism, which stores key-value pairs in the browser itself.  Mozilla browsers also support a (proprietary) WebDatabase technology, which allows you to access an SQLite database through the browser.  But even then, it’s the browser who determines where that database will be stored.

For a single-page, client-only app, I suggest you read http://www.diveintohtml5.org; it’s very informative and will bring you up to speed as to the new HTML technologies that can be used.  If it’s too complex for you, then I suggest starting with a regular HTML tutorial first.

If you really want to be able to access a database, then you’re going to need some kind of server-side technology.  For experimentation purposes, you could try [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (or PHP/Apache, or one of a host of ‘regular’ web application frameworks).

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer (need 15) or I would do so. This at least is enough info for me to stop looking for that mythical solution (I think modrnizr is too specialized for the browser set that will use this) and turn to a scripting language like PHP or Python. Appreciate the comment.